# Pushing the logs from IdentityServer to sumoLogic via SerilLog: How we can combine sequential related log entries to one

Tags: azure, identityserver4, serilog, sumologic

We are using IdentityServer4 and sending logs to SumoLogic.
We are pushing the logs from IdentityServer to sumoLogic via SerilLog and SumoLogic treats each log entry as a separate message. So whats happening is basically one error is getting reported as two or more different messages:

Log entry1:
2017-09-11 16:06:28.234 +10:00 [Information] Request finished in 2265.5543ms 400 application/json

Log entry2:
2017-09-11 16:06:28.230 +10:00 [Debug] Connection id ""0HL7ORC9RFJ8C"" completed keep alive response.

Log entry3:
2017-09-11 16:06:28.209 +10:00 [Error] "{
  \"ClientId\": \"roclient.reference\",
  \"GrantType\": \"password\",
  \"Raw\": {
    \"grant_type\": \"password\",
    \"username\": \"BobSmith@email.com\",
    \"password\": \"***REDACTED***\",
    \"scope\": \"api1 api2.read_only\"
  }
}"

Log entry4:
2017-09-11 16:06:28.189 +10:00 [Error] Requested scope not allowed: "api1" ; ApiScope not found: ""

Log entry5:
2017-09-11 16:06:28.180 +10:00 [Debug] Found "" API scopes in database

But our reporting facility is SumoLogic which treats each entry as single-one and each entry when extracted doesn’t give full information and what I want to know is the way how we can combine these sequential messages to one.

Is there anything that we can do as on IdentityServer4/Sumologic/SeriLog.

Thanks,
Neha

Answer (score 0):

I would try changing the output of SeriLog to JSON, see this link: https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Formatting-Output

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.File(new JsonFormatter(), "log.txt")
    .CreateLogger();
```

Let me know if this works for you.